Amazon Connect Streams - Headless
Is there a way to use Amazon Connect Streams API without embedding the CCP or the Agent App into your website like a headless mode? I want to build my own agent UI and customize the chat experience for the agent. I got this to work, but this still embeds the Agent App. I want to build my own UI for chat.
This works (I get the events I need), but still embeds the agent app into a div.
connect.agentApp.initApp(name, containerId, appUrl, config)
Is there a way to get this to work without embedding the default UI?

No, the native CCP must be part of the page. However, you can hide it with CSS so it shouldn’t be a problem to customise the UI.
